# Kindle (2nd gen) battery can't hold power

Tags: kindle, battery

I bought a Kindle some years ago. At first I used it a lot, then I left it unused. I would like to use it again: only trouble is that the battery can't mantain the charge. This is not surprising, it's an 8 year old device, but using it plugged to the wall is not practical.

Is there something that I can do? I searched the [Amazon help page](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200375430) but I was unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to change the battery.

A simple [Google search](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=it&q=kindle%202nd%20gen%20replace%20battery&oq=kindle%202nd%20gen%20replace%20battery) returns a lot of results, I summarize here the steps from [this page](http://www.hackwriting.com/2012/10/17/how-to-replace-a-kindle-2-battery/):

> 1. Turn off your Kindle. Slide and hold the power switch for four
>      seconds, then release. The screen blanks.
> 2. Place the Kindle screen down on a flat, clean surface.
> 3. Remove the plastic back panel. Two tabs keep the back panel in
>      place. Use a thin spudger to slide the panel away from the larger
>      metal back panel. This step is a little scary while you do it. You will think you’re breaking the Kindle, but as long as you apply only
>      gentle force, you won’t actually break anything.
> 4. Remove the metal back panel. With a Phillips #0 screwdriver, remove the two screws which attach the metal back panel to the
>      Kindle’s plastic body, then slide the panel away. Until you replace
>      the back panels, keep a close eye on the volume rocker. Without the
>      back panels to hold it into position, it may fall out.
> 5. Remove the old battery. With a Phillips #0 screwdriver, remove the two screws holding the battery in place, then lift the battery out by
>      its black tabs.
> 6. Install the new battery. Drop it in connector first, then replace the two retaining screws.
> 7. Replace the metal back panel. Place it such that the panel lies flat and the volume rocker is held in place, then replace the two
>      retaining screws.
> 8. Replace the plastic back panel. Place it such that the panel lies flat and the volume rocker is held in place, then slide it toward the
>      bottom of the Kindle.
> 9. Recharge the Kindle with a micro USB cable. After a few seconds, the amber light will illuminate and the screen will refresh.

You can also try [this](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Kindle+2+Battery+Replacement/14081) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ymli5IbOtSo).

Comment: That's really a good guide, with pics and explanation of tools. I will get a reputable battery and do it.

Answer (score 1):

A not so comfortable but less dangerous solution might be to connect the Kindle with a short USB cable (e.g. 6 inch long) to a small powerbank (the question states that the device is working while it is connected to a power source). So while reading you have also to hold the powerbank, which should have a handy shape for this (e.g. rather flat and approximately same size as the kindle).